# Coffeescript compilation variations (coffeescript.org vs coffee-rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, compilation, coffeescript

I'm attempting to write a simple github API call in coffeescript, but have been running into inconsistencies which I can't explain between coffeescript.org and the coffee-rails gem. I have checked for a mix of tabs/spaces more times than I can count, and feel there must be something subtle or stupid that I'm missing.

**Original Code**

```
$ ->
  gistids = ['5100088']
  for gistid in gistids
    $.ajax
      url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/'+gistid,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    .success (gistdata) ->
      console.log(gistdata.data.files)
    .fail (e) ->
      console.log(e)
```

**Coffeescript.org Compilation**

It happily compiles to the following on coffeescript.org (and when run via the console, functions exactly as expected).

```
$(function() {
  var gistid, gistids, _i, _len, _results;
  gistids = ['5100088'];
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = gistids.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    gistid = gistids[_i];
    _results.push($.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/' + gistid,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).success(function(gistdata) {
      return console.log(gistdata.data.files);
    }).fail(function(e) {
      return console.log(e);
    }));
  }
  return _results;
});
```

**Rails-coffee gem Compilation** (this is my output)

The alternate compilation is obviously destined for failure, and doesn't seem even close to what I'm trying to achieve. It almost looks like the `for` loop is trying to execute the contents as you'd expect in `eat food for food in ['toast', 'cheese', 'wine']` type syntax?

This code is also output if you use another online 'try coffeescript' type site, such as http://www.compileonline.com/try_coffeescript_online.php

```
  $(function() {
    var gistid, gistids, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
    _ref = gistids($.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/' + gistid,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp'.success(function(gistdata) {
        return console.log(gistdata.data.files).fail(function(e) {
          return console.log(e);
        });
      })
    }));
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      gistid = _ref[_i];
      _results.push(gistids = ['5100088']);
    }
    return _results;
  });
```

What have I missed? Is there a major change between the versions being used, a compilation flag difference, a small syntactical error which is being overlooked, or have I gotten it completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue, but am no closer to finding an answer as to why it has changed.

I was able to change and recompile the code, with changes being reflected in the code (still incorrectly compiled). I decided to retype the code by hand in another coffeescript file, which worked perfectly. I then copy/pasted over my retyped code, and it still worked in the other file.

I then swapped the contents from my existing coffeescript file over to the file I was having issues with, and it wouldn't even compile. I renamed the file, thinking that perhaps there was some naming restrictions I was unaware of, and it began to compile correctly. I then changed the file name back, and it still compiles perfectly. Note that above I mentioned the compilation *was* being updated with changes, just compiling incorrectly (it wasn't an old version).

The strange thing here, is that I was able to undo all changes and recover the code which was having issues. Copying this into compileronline still caused the same problems, but copying the new code worked perfectly. I did a diff comparison between the old and new code, and it reported no differences, even though the above was entirely repeatable.

All I can assume is this *was* a whitespace/character issue which wasn't being shown in the diff, even though retyping by hand didn't seem to fix it the first time, until the file was changed. I have yelled at the world about the injustice of this enough and I need to move on, but I would be very interested if anyone had a more solid reason for this.